# How does this directive close?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this code basically creates a directive thats an element with a close link.

there is an ng-click with a close() function linked to it. What is the process that is happending during the close event like what is called next?
I can't seam to find the close function in the controller?

```
helloWorldControllers.controller("alertCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.showAlert = true;
$scope.alertTopic = "Something went wrong!";
$scope.alertMessage = "You must inform the plate and the color of the car!";
$scope.closeAlert = function () {
    $scope.showAlert = false;
};
});
helloWorldControllers.directive("alert", function () {
return {
    scope: {
        topic: '=topic',
        description: '=description',
        close: '&close'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div class='alert' style='color: #FF0000; position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF' >" +
    "<span class='alert-topic' ng-class='cName'>" +
    '<span ng-bind="topic"></span>' +
      "</span>" +
    "<span class='alert-description'>" +
    '<span ng-bind="description"></span>' +
    "</span>" +
    '<a href="" ng-click="close()">Close</a>' +
    "</div>"
};
});
```

`<div ng-controller="alertCtrl">
    <alert ng-show="showAlert"  topic="alertTopic" description="descriptionTopic" close="closeAlert()"
    >
    </alert>
</div>`

Comment: Can you share your html where you used this directive ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive takes in an expression called `close` which gets wrapped as a function by Angular:

```
scope: {
    // ...
    close: '&close'
},
```

In this case, you'd pass in the `closeAlert` function defined on the controller, and control visibility using `ng-if` (or `ng-show`):

```
<alert ng-if="showAlert" close="closeAlert()"></alert>
```

Also note that since the `close` property and its value (`&close`) have the same name, you can do this:

```
scope: {
    // ...
    close: '&'
},
```

Comment: Is the close property part of angular? I can't seem to find information about it on the web?

Comment: No, this is how you create custom reusable directives. You allow the person using the directive to pass in data and callbacks (using the `scope` object in the directive). In this case, the directive allows you to pass in a function that defines what to do when the close button is clicked, along with a topic and description.

Comment: What I don't seam to see is how the closeAlert function is closing the element? all it does is return a Boolean expression? I don't see any DOM manipulation going on? Or any other logic for this to happen?

Comment: In this particular case, I don't see any code which actually closes anything. But the markup looks like it may come from Bootstrap. So either this directive is unfinished, or if bootstrap is loaded it's possible there is JavaScript in the page already that will close the alert when the button is clicked. See this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissible

Comment: Actually, I think I'm wrong in the above comment. It looks like the directive was intended to be used like this: `<alert ng-if="showAlert" close="closeAlert()"></alert>`

Comment: No bootstrap is not loaded it's just the controller and the directive.

Comment: Ok so the logic is <alert ng-if="showAlert" close="closeAlert()"></alert> ok this make more sense. I'll try do some more researech based on this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The `&` binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an
>   expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.
>   Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which
>   contains a function call. Because of this, `&` bindings are ideal for
>   binding callback functions to directive behaviors.

When the user clicks "Close" in the alert, the directive's `close` function is called, thanks to ng-click. This call to `close` on the isolated scope actually evaluates the expression `closeAlert()` in the context of the original scope, 
thus running `closeAlert` function of `alertCtrl` controller, assuming it was passed like `close="closeAlert()"`.